# How to make a reusable view accept generic types

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiview, customstringconvertible

I created a reusable control to be used in a project I'm working on. It's just a `UITextField` which shows a `UIPickerView` as its `inputView`.

[image]

```
class InputPickerView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet private var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak private var textField: UITextField!

    private(set) var pickerView = UIPickerView()

    var options: [String] = []

    var option: String {
        get {
            return textField.text ?? ""
        }
        set {
            textField.text = newValue
        }
    }

    var title: String = "" {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InputPickerView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(view)
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        textField.inputView = pickerView
    }
}

extension InputPickerView: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

extension InputPickerView: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return options[row]
    }
}

extension InputPickerView: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textField.text = options[row]
    }
}
```

Currently it only accepts an array of strings and returns a string. I'm trying to make it even more reusable by make it accept/return any types such as structs and enums with the help of generics. I was hoping to make the structs/enums conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and use the description property value as the display value for the picker view options.

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. All the articles, questions, tutorials I came across have protocols involved in them. So I'm a little confused.

How can I make the `options` and `option` variables accept/return any type with generics?

By which I mean, say I create an object called `State`.

```
struct State {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}

extension State: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return title
    }
}
```

Instead of passing in strings to the view, I'm trying to make it accept instances of `State` objects in the `options` property and have the view use the `description` value as the display value. And when the user selects one, it returns the selected `State` object via the `option` property.

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39zuuu2cpnmw9we/genericpickerview.zip?dl=0)

Comment: it can be done via protocols

Comment: @jawadAli Could you please elaborate? Or point me to an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "return any types"?

Comment: @Rob I updated my question with some explanations :)

Comment: @Isuru It's doable but you'd have to use generics. And if you use generics, you can't use a xib for your `InputPickerView`. How do you feel about laying out your view programmatically?

Comment: Oh I see. I don't normally create UIs programatically but if that's the only way, I'm fine with it. I'll look into replicating the UI in code. Just need some help with the generics part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a protocol that extracts a string from your conforming types to display in the picker:

```
protocol Presentable {
    var title: String { get }
}
```

Make your `State` struct conform to `Presentable`:

```
struct State: Presentable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}
```

Add some generic constraints to your `InputPickerView` and whenever you need the text from your model just reference the `title` property. Note that if you use generics you can no longer create extensions for your `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods.

```
class InputPickerView<OptionType: Presentable>: UIView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    private var textField: UITextField!

    var options: [OptionType] = []

    var selectedOption: OptionType?

    var title: String = "" {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }

    // ... Other stuff you need to add ...

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return options[row].title
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textField.text = options[row].title
        selectedOption = options[row]
    }
}
```

You create your `InputPickerView` like this:

```
let pickerView = InputPickerView<State>()
pickerView.options = [
    State(id: 1, title: "First"),
    State(id: 2, title: "Second"),
    State(id: 3, title: "Third"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was going for.